# Empty space at right and bottom on mobile version of website

Tags: android, html, wordpress, mobile

my website (www.primapaginaonline.it) has a problem when browsed from a smartphone (at least from android, on a Nokia Lumia with Internet Explorer looks fine). It has big empty space at right and at bottom of the page. I can't understand why it looks like that.
Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your website have some css issues 
in following elements listed below:

document.getElementById("footerwrapper1") --> Responsible for Horizontal Scroll
document.getElementsByClassName('secondary') --> Responsible for Vertical Scroll

by changing css property display:none to both of them, 
Unnecessary scroll is removed.

Comment: Thank you! The issue is gone!

Comment: Hi, I've noted that the issue is gone on the home page but remains in the internal pages, like http://www.primapaginaonline.it/2014/06/24/gran-gala-di-circo-al-palafolli/

Thanks

Comment: same issue: check for document.getElementsByClassName('social-container') in the page your mentioned. and please mark this answer, if this solved your problem. thanks